# Get the name of image used in ImageButton

Tags: android

I have an `Integer` array containing the `id` of finite number of images. I have an `ImageButton` in which I am embedding an image randomly from the above array once the `ImageButton` is clicked. Since the images are embedded randomly, I want to know the name of the image which is currently applied to the `ImageButton` every time the `ImageButton` is clicked.

*minSDK=21 and Device API Level=29*

Here is the code:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);
    Integer[] imageIds={R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five,R.drawable.six};
    final ImageButton btn= findViewById(R.id.dice);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random gen = new Random();
            int randomImg = imageIds[gen.nextInt(imageIds.length)];
            btn.setImageResource(randomImg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It is just `randomImg` . If you want to have it as a string like "three", you should use a switch-case statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the name of the resource from the resource id in this way:

```
String name = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(randomImg);
```